# What is causing SCNNodes not to touch each others when using physics with ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to place objects on top of each others, but for some reason the physics are not working as they should. When I drop items on top of other items there's always some space which remains between the items. What is that space and how can I get rid of it?

As you can see in the picture below, there're three objects stacked on top of each others. This is what always happens when I place them on top of each others.

[image]

This is how I create the plane and add physics to it:

```
private func createPlaneWithPhysics(planeCenter pos: vector_float3) -> SCNNode {
    let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
    let planeGeometry = SCNBox(width: defaultPlaneWidth, height: 0.01, length: defaultPlaneHeight, chamferRadius: 0)
    planeGeometry.materials = [planeMaterial]
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(pos.x, pos.y - DimensionCorrection.yAxisError, pos.z)
    let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: planeGeometry, options: nil)
    let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: shape)
    planeNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
    planeNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Int(SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory.static.rawValue)
    planeNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Int(SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory.default.rawValue)
    return planeNode
}
```

And in the VirtualContainer I add physics for the VirtualItem(.physicsBody) in the following way:

```
private func physicsForvirtualItem() -> SCNPhysicsBody {
    let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: virtualItem, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type : SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox])
    let physics = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: shape)
    physics.mass = virtualItem.mass
    physics.isAffectedByGravity = true
    physics.velocityFactor = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
    physics.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
    physics.categoryBitMask = Int(SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory.default.rawValue)
    return physics
}
```

Comment: sceneView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes

Comment: The shape is a bounding box for each object, so with turning it on it looks exactly the same as this picture but the lines are just green.

Comment: without seeing your code its a guessing game. If you can edit your question and add the code for handling the physicsBody and collisions it will be much easier to solve the issue.

Comment: There's some code now.

Answer (score 1):

The physicShape wasn’t moving when I used node: instead of geometry: in the physicsShape method... see my approach below - set a primitive geometry to the physicShape node.

```
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: virtualItem, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type : SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.convexHull])
```

When you import geometry created in external 3D authoring packages, the default pivots & bounding boxes can be very unpredictable. To troubleshoot you might just create a simple box geometry and apply it to your imported or irregular geometry.

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 0.05, height: 0.05, length: 0.05, chamferRadius: 0)

let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type : SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.convexHull])
let physics = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: shape)
```

I think it might have something to do with using node instead of geometry

if the box is not centered on the geometry the pivot needs to be centred using a centerPivot function like...

```
func centerPivot(for node: SCNNode) {
     var min = SCNVector3Zero
    var max = SCNVector3Zero
    node.__getBoundingBoxMin(&min, max: &max)
    node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(
        min.x + (max.x - min.x)/2,
        min.y + (max.y - min.y)/2,
        min.z + (max.z - min.z)/2
    )
}
```

to use just

```
 centerPivot(for: node!)
```

[image]

Comment: this is likely the answer to his problems, I've used this exact func before and it worked well for me on some of my sketchy models.

Comment: As I mentioned before and you can see in the code(/picture), the physics shape is set as a bounding box manually and it's set correctly around the SCNNode so the pivot must be right too (I can see in the model editor that it's in the correct place too). Also when I move the object I always do physicsBody?.resetTransform() so the physicsShape is following the node. But I noticed in an example project (https://github.com/markdaws/arkit-by-example/tree/part3) the same thing, sometimes the boxes floats though most of the time they will rest on each others.

Comment: Problem solved. It seems like that for some reason the actual physics shape is stays as convex hull even though I add the physics shape as a bounding box manually in the code. Anyways it started working after I set the physics body in the Scene Editor as a bounding box. Really weird.

Comment: But thanks a lot Ash for your time and help. Thanks to you I was able the get my mind straight and find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using nil or the standard shapes for the collision geometry is designed for speed -- not for correctness.  Just use the actual geometry of the SCNNode instead of one of the standard shapes.  Today's devices are fast so you are probably fine doing this in many cases.

Something like this, assuming you have your SCNNode already set up with its associated geometry, either from code, or by importing a .dae or .scn file:

```
let node = SCNNode()
// (add geometry via code or init node from scene loaded from file)
let pShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node.geometry)
let pBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: pShape)
// (add any other physicsBody setup stuff)
node.physicsBody = pBody
```